# PDOStatement wrong result on check

Tags: php, database, mysqli, pdo, statements

I am having this code:

```html
$PDOStatement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (ID, email, password) VALUES(?, ?, ?)");

    if($PDOStatement->execute($uuid, $email,$encrypted_password))
    {
        echo "test";
        return true;
    }
```

The data gets entered into the DB, but unforunetly the IF is not giving out the echo or the return.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: remove the return

Comment: why is this tagged as mysqli?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Hi, thanks for the fast answer :) I attached the return after it didn't work before

Comment: And, well, I am very new to MySQL, basically started this week and on one page I saw MySQLi and the other said only MySQL, so I was not clear.

Comment: outside your IF, try `print_r($PDOStatement->errorInfo());` what does that output?

Comment: Hi @James :) It gives out this Before the IF: Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => )  After: Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the parameters as an array:

```
if($PDOStatement->execute($uuid, $email,$encrypted_password))
```

should be

```
if($PDOStatement->execute([$uuid, $email,$encrypted_password]))
```

(Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)